# How to Add Custom Field to a Buddypress Update

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I would like to add a simple `_custom_field` to buddypress activity updates so that when you post a buddypress activity update there is an additional input field where I enter text, whenever that update is displayed in the activity stream, the update template should display the `_custom_field` aswell

Answer (score 1):

This did it, You have to modify the activity post form to add the new input field then you create a function in bp-custom.php/functions.php to post that new value to the database, this will only work after modifying the javascript that processes the form, the following link gives a clear walk through

https://buddypress.org/support/topic/adding-a-second-element-for-posting-with-an-activity/